# Values of Google OAuth consent screen for mobile app

Tags: android, google-oauth

I'm developing a mobile application where a user can sign in using Google. I'm setting up for "Google OAuth consent screen", where I've mentioned the URL of my site along with a logo and the links of the privacy policy, and T&C. It is by default taking the scopes: OpenID, email, and profile. I've submitted the request for verification.

I've received an e-mail from Google to share the link of web log-in which is not valid in my case. What I'm missing?

> After further review of your request, we see that your home page URL https://example.com contains no content for users to view (as shown in the screenshot attached). We would need to test the sign-up flow on the app as a part of the review process.
>
> For us to proceed with the verification process, please provide us with a working link of your app where we could test the OAuth flow for the scopes that you have requested.

Should I launch the app first before setting up the consent screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The settings I did was correct. There was not any issue. I've dropped an email to the Google team and they approved it.